Descended directory listing of python3 -m http.server
I tried this
python3 -m http server

Returning html:
Directory listing for /
20240505041828.jpg
20240505041830.jpg
20240505041832.jpg
20240505041833.jpg
20240505042221.jpg
20240505042222.jpg
20240505042224.jpg
20240505042226.jpg
20240505042227.jpg
20240505042229.jpg
20240505042231.jpg

I expect descended listing instead of ascending. It will be best solution if I just need add some flags directly in command instead of writing/creating new script.
